# What does "to fix a book" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

This context comes from the movie "The Aviator" by Martin Scorsese. It's from a  scene that goes after another one, in which Howard Hughes tells his employee, Noah (who he hired to run his company for him, so he can fully devote himself to making movies), that he wants to reshoot the long-awaited movie they just finished making because of the introduction of sound into the film, which happened just before the premiere. Noah asked him how much it's going to cost, to which Howard replies "1.7 million, we got that much?". Noah emphatically replies that they don't and Howard's response is "Well we'll make it".
This is the sentence Noah utters in the next scene when starting a conversation with Howard a few weeks later.

"I've been on the phone to Houston for three solid hours now -- we been **fixing every goddamn book** we have but.."

So I assume this has to do with making money for the movie because this is the only goal that he's been charged with. The only definition for "fix" I was able to find which makes any sense is:

a. To correct or set right; adjust: *fix a misspelling; fix the out-of-date accounts.*(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

Does it mean that Noah is **correcting records of transactions that the company makes in order to find out whether there are any available funds for reshooting the movie**?

Comment: "Fixing the books" or "cooking the books" usually means to produce false accounting records. I think this line is meant to extend this idiom, but it's not the usual usage.

Comment: In other contexts, we might call this unusual variant of the idiomatic standard "wordplay", but in exactly this context you *might* accept it as a credible "neologistic" udsage. Except of course in the real world it ***is*** wordplay (by the ***scriptwriter,*** who doubtless chuckled to himself as he penned the line).